# ispell for windows 7 for flyspell mode?

Tags: windows-7, emacs

Could anyone point me to the site where I can get the ispell.exe for Windows 7?

I need to run flyspell mode on emacs/win32, but it doesn't work as I don't have the ispell.

### ADDED

I found the ispell that works with emacs/win32.
One should use the one that works with emacs/win32 as is explained in [the book of emacs](http://book.chinaunix.net/special/ebook/oreilly/LearningGnuEmacs/0596006489/gnu3-CHP-13-SECT-3.html).

1. Download ispell.zip from one of the [site](http://www.filewatcher.com/m/ispell.zip.352502.0.0.html).
2. Copy the ispell.exe to the PATH directory, and copy the English dictionary to the home directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might have more luck with [aspell](http://aspell.net/). Aspell will work as a drop-in replacement for ispell with flyspell mode.

I have answered a related question on StackOverflow: [emacs windows spell check aspell or hunspell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012361/emacs-windows-spell-check-aspell-or-hunspell/2012470#2012470)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this solution? http://bria.nwood.org/node/49

Dos version of ispell: http://www.projectory.de/ispell/

anyway you can always install cygwin and compile ispell by yourself with ming compiler - manual is here http://www.delorie.com/howto/cygwin/mno-cygwin-howto.html